# What's the default enum value in Protobuf?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Hello
What's the default enum value (if there isn't any default value defined) in Google Protocol buffer using with Java?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is the first one defined in .proto order.

From the .proto language guide (since all implementations use the same logic here):

> ### Optional Fields And Default Values
>
> (snip) For enums, the default value is the first value listed in the enum's type definition.

Comment: So it's a good idea to make the first one be zero and mean something like "unknown".

Comment: @poolie well, I tend to do that for *unrelated* reasons; but since a number of languages like to default things to zero, having an enum with value zero can be useful, even if that is `None` or `Default`.

Comment: Since you cant set null you are forced to create a null value for each enum ? Not cool ...

Comment: @TheBakker the only time that would cause *any* problem is if you're using your DTO types as your domain types. As I always say to people: *the very moment* that there is a conflict between what you serializer needs and what you want in your domain model: **split them** - use a separate DTO model and map between them in the code that touches the serializer

Comment: Not using the generated protobuf java object in my business, still, it means adding extra value to enums just to handle null case.
Wish there was a simple way to customise the generated protobuf to java converter.

Comment: @TheBakker ultimately, "null" / "no value" isn't a thing that exists in the protobuf specification - except for "optional" single messages (but not "repeated"); a little limiting in some scenarios, yes

Comment: And since in the same namespace, 2 enums can't have the same value, I'll have to create different null value for each of my enum (or different namespace). Arg ... Anyway thanks for your confirmation @Marc

Comment: @TheBakker blame C/C++ :)

Answer (score 6):

from [the official spec](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html):

> optional: the field may or may not be
>   set. If an optional field value isn't
>   set, a default value is used. For
>   simple types, you can specify your own
>   default value, as we've done for the
>   phone number type in the example.
>   Otherwise, a system default is used:
>   zero for numeric types, the empty
>   string for strings, false for bools.
>   For embedded messages, the default
>   value is always the "default instance"
>   or "prototype" of the message, which
>   has none of its fields set. Calling
>   the accessor to get the value of an
>   optional (or required) field which has
>   not been explicitly set always returns
>   that field's default value.

You can set a default value as follows:

```
optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
```

Comment: yes, but my question is what's the default value if there isn't any defined? the offical spec just mentions for other types then enums.